# Adding lines to a video game script to futureproof a project

Tags: dialogue, videogame

Sometimes, video game development can go awry, so I want to add extra lines in case there's a decision to add generic questlines and new game mechanics. So how do you come up with a lot of lines that are likely to be useful and that can be spliced in several ways to futureproof the project?

Comment: Could you say more about how these lines of dialogue are used?  I'm puzzled that it sounds like you need to have the dialogue before the game elements are added, but I'n not a game developer so I don't know how this is usually done.

Comment: This is really going to depend on how your game is designed and what it is made with. Time you spend future proofing your project is time not spent actually making and improving the project.

Comment: Try a software stack exchange.  I don't see this as a writing question.

Comment: Placeholders like "blah blah" work wonders in most cases

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would fit better on Game Development Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Without having very much information, I would suggest that you come up with a number of generic statements with variables instead of specific words such that they can be used in a multitude of situations. For example:

"Please, you have to help! X and Y!"

In that line, (X, Y) could be anything from ("my husband cheated on me", "I don't know how to go on") to ("the prince has been kidnapped", "the king has been assassinated"):

"Please, you have to help! My husband cheated on me and I don't know how to go on!"

"Please, you have to help! The prince has been kidnapped and the king has been assassinated!"

That single sentence structure just created two completely different scenarios with different intensities and expected difficulty levels. It's basic, but that's all you need for an initial idea. Later on you can tailor whatever generic ideas you come up with to better fit the specific storylines and the game in general.